# Informatica datatype conversion

Tags: informatica

wanted to have two columns separate in target table

- Column: CTDATE in `YYYYMMDD` Format
- Column: CTTIME in `HHMMSS` Format.

How can I populate in Expression Transformation? What is the expression used? 
Please guys, help me out.

I used

- TO_CHAR(in_column, 'YYYYMMDD') for CTDATE
- TO_CHAR(in_column, 'HHMISS') for CTTIME

Comment: What's the input? Are you reading from some database or a file?

Answer (score 1):

If your `in_column` type is already `date/time` then what you are using right now is almost correct, except use `HH24MISS` instead of `HHMISS`. Or use `HH12MISS AM`.

- TO_CHAR(in_column, 'YYYYMMDD') for CTDATE
- TO_CHAR(in_column, 'HH24MISS') for CTTIME

If `in_column` is a `string`, the first convert it to a `date/time`. Suppose `in_column` is coming as `'Jan 24 2017 14:24:56'` then

- first create a variable `v_in_column` as `TO_DATE( in_column, 'MON DD
  YYYY HH24:MI:SS' )`
- Then use this variable to derive `CTDATE` and
  `CTTIME`

  - TO_CHAR(v_in_column, 'YYYYMMDD') for CTDATE
  - TO_CHAR(v_in_column, 'HHMISS') for CTTIME